# Implications of setting cookie expire time

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, architecture

I think this is a matter of personal choice, but is it any difference in performance or style when setting cookie expire time like this:

```
var expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
```

or like this:

```
var expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 31536000000); // one year in milliseconds
```

Comment: not really. doing the math in advance will shave a few microseconds off processing time, but it won't even be measurable with a modern computer. on the other hand, with the top one i can clearly tell that's a year, whereas with the bottom one i would have to do some division to figure out how long that is. primarily opinion based question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as style would go, nested date objects are already kind of weird, regardless of doing the math during execution or not.

The performance is negligible as well.

Heres my recommedation:

```
var expires = new Date();
expires.setFullYear(expires.getFullYear() + 1);
```

This makes it pretty obvious that you're simply adding a year to the current date.